# Different data source for each Select Box widget output

Tags: shiny

I have 3 data sources in my select box widget.  I am trying to have my graph update when I choose a different data source from the select box in the app.  The graph is not updating when I change the data source though.  Do I need to use the `reactive` command?

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Temperature Data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("dataSelection", label = "Choose a Data Set", choices = c("Dataset 1", "Dataset 2")),
      selectInput("component1", label = "Choose a Chart",
                  choices = c("Watts"),
                  selected = "Watts" )),

    mainPanel(
      dygraphOutput("TempRise")

    )
    )




#server.r
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {

      output$TempRise <- renderDygraph({

        dataSource <- switch(input$dataSelection,
                     "Dataset 1" = Data1,
                     "Dataset 2" = Data2)

        TempData <- switch(input$component1,
                       "Watts" = dataSource$Watts)
    dygraph(TempData, main = "Temperature Data") %>%
          dyRangeSelector()

    })
    })
```

Comment: what is `dyRangeSelector()`? and show what `Data1` and `Data2` looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is an example of two datasets provided with R, note that they are time-series. For more information about `dygraphs` you can refer to [dygraphs for R - Using in Shiny Applications](https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/shiny.html)

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Sample Data"),
    sidebarPanel(selectInput("dataSelection", label = "Choose a Data Set", choices = c("Dataset 1", "Dataset 2"))),
  mainPanel(dygraphOutput("TempRise"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # Note that the data is a timeseries, make sure to convert into a time series object
  dataSource <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataSelection,"Dataset 1" = LakeHuron,"Dataset 2" = AirPassengers)
  })

  output$TempRise <- renderDygraph({ dygraph(dataSource(), main = "Sample Data")})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]